# How can I move the paragraph below the background?

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I have a web development assignment due soon. I really need help putting the course info paragraph below the non-repeat background. I do not want it to be on the same 2 pics the Computer Engineering Title is on. Also, how can I change the 
font of it? Any help will be appreciated :). This is due very soon.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

.jumbotron {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: url(image.jpg);
  background-position: 0% 25%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #330;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
}

.navigation a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  color: black;
}

.navigation a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-image: url("Engineering.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 4;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

.courseinfo {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>
    Home - Hasan's Website
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
    <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    <a href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#webDev">Web Development</a>
  </div>

  <div class="intro">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Computer Engineering</h1>

    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="courseinfo">
    <p>This course examines computer systems and control of external devices. Students will develop knowledge and skills in electronics, interfacing, programming, and networks, will build systems that use computer programs and interfaces to control and respond
      to external devices. Students will develop an awareness of related environmental and societal issues, and will learn about college and university programs leading to careers in computer technology.</p>

  </div>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: by adding `position:absolute` it will cause the element below to go behind that specific `element`, just remove `position:absolute from it`

Comment: I removed position: absolute and it made the Computer Engineering title move to the corner.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Can u add the final requirement screenshot?

Comment: Let me try..... https://gyazo.com/58954bbc04aa47a793536e62ec021677 I spammed <br> in the code to get this view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this how you want it.. removed
`position:absolute` and  `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`
added background image to `.intro`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

.jumbotron {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-image: url(image.jpg);
  background-position: 0% 25%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #330;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
}

.navigation a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  color: black;
}

.navigation a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.intro {
  background-image: url("Engineering.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 4;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

.courseinfo {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>
    Home - Hasan's Website
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
    <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    <a href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#webDev">Web Development</a>
  </div>

  <div class="intro">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Computer Engineering</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="courseinfo">
    <p>This course examines computer systems and control of external devices. Students will develop knowledge and skills in electronics, interfacing, programming, and networks, will build systems that use computer programs and interfaces to control and respond
      to external devices. Students will develop an awareness of related environmental and societal issues, and will learn about college and university programs leading to careers in computer technology.</p>

  </div>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You were close. I want the current backgrounds to have "Computer Engineering"
 in it. The paragraph should be under the background, where there is no background.

Comment: @John Bob check now. i have updated my answer. thanks

Comment: Sorry, that just got rid of the large background and pushed everything to the top.

Comment: you are not clear what you want.. please add a screenshot

Comment: Sure. https://gyazo.com/ded725b3b25947f362af087f62885e3d I want the text below the background so I can scroll down to it.

Comment: you want the background to take full width of the screen??

Comment: I want the blue background to take full width but non-repeat. I want the blue background just for the computer engineering.  I want to put the paragraph underneath the blue background.

Comment: You were SO close! The paragraph is positioned properly, but the computer engineering got pushed to the top. I want the Computer Engineering to stay in the middle of the blue background.

Comment: check now. added `display: flex;`   `align-items: center;` to .intro class

Comment: Nice! You got the paragraph under the background! I changed the 90vh to 100% so the background can look nice to the eye when it is first opened. We are making great progress! The only thing left is that the Computer Engineering is not centered. It is pushed to the side. Do you know how to fix this? Thank you for helping me BTW.

Comment: add `justify-content: center` to `.intro` class